# How to get a placeholder/dummy step in SageMaker pipelines?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'd like to sketch out some steps in a SageMaker pipeline, and only fill them in one at a time, but I don't think there's an EmptyStep option anywhere.

I've considered using some vacuously true ConditionalSteps, or subclassing `sagemaker.workflow.steps.Step`, but the former can't be chained, and the latter seems likely to break things, given my implementation wouldn't necessarily conform to what the service is looking for.

Is there a good way to go about this? An empty processor step?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to create your own empty step in a SageMaker Pipeline. The easiest way for you to achieve this would be to use a LambdaStep and create stub Lambda functions. With a processor you will pay the penalty of cold start for each job.

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.